# a simple modification of a for loop

Tags: php

I have a simple php script that counts the number of pages in a manga script :

```
$omv_pager = "";

$omv_pager .= "<div class=\"well\">\n";

$omv_pager .= "<span>Manga <select class=\"form-control\" style='margin-bottom:10px;' name=\"manga\" onchange=\"change_manga(this.value)\">";
$omv_pager .= "<option class=\"form-control\" value=\"0\">Selecione Título do Manga...</option>";
for ($i = 0; $i < count($mangas); $i++) {
    $m = $mangas[$i];
    $omv_pager .= "<option value=\"" . omv_encode($m) . "\"" . (($m == $manga) ? " selected=\"selected\"" : "") . ">" . $m . "</option>";
}
$omv_pager .= "</select></span>\n";

if ($manga) {
    if ($chapter) {
        $omv_pager .= "<span>Chapter <select name=\"chapter\" onchange=\"change_chapter('$manga_escaped', this.value)\">";
        for ($i = 0; $i < count($chapters); $i++) {
            $cnumber = $chapters[$i]["number"];
            $omv_pager .= "<option value=\"" . omv_encode($cnumber) . "\"" . (($cnumber == $chapter_number) ? " selected=\"selected\"" : "") . ">" . $cnumber . (isset($chapters[$i]["title"]) ? (" - " . $chapters[$i]["title"]) : "") . "</option>";
        }
        $omv_pager .= "</select></span>\n";

        if ($page) {
            $prevhtml = "";
            if ($page <= 1) {
                $prevhtml = "<img src=\"http://www.leitor.tk/themes/default/no-previous.png\" alt=\"\" />";
            } else {
                $prevhtml = "<a href=\"$manga_escaped/$chapter_number_escaped/" . ($page - 1) . "\"><img src=\"http://www.leitor.tk/themes/default/previous.png\" alt=\"Previous Page\" title=\"Previous Page\" /></a>";
            }
            $nexthtml = "";
            if ($page >= count($pages)) {
                $nexthtml = "<img src=\"http://www.leitor.tk/themes/default/no-next.png\" alt=\"\" />";
            } else {
                $nexthtml = "<a href=\"$manga_escaped/$chapter_number_escaped/" . ($page + 1) . "\"><img src=\"http://www.leitor.tk/themes/default/next.png\" alt=\"Next Page\" title=\"Next Page\" /></a>";
            }

             $omv_pager .= "<span>$prevhtml Page <select name=\"page\" onchange=\"change_page('$manga_escaped', '$chapter_number_escaped', this.value)\">";
                                    for ($p = 1; $p <= count($pages); $p++) {
                                            $omv_pager .= "<option value=\"" . $p . "\"" . (($p == $page) ? " selected=\"selected\"" : "") . ">" . $p . "</option>";
                                    }
                                    $omv_pager .= "</select> of " . count($pages) . " $nexthtml</span>\n";
                            }
                    }
            }

$omv_pager .= "</div>\n";

echo $omv_pager;
```

What I want to do is, in the last page change the name of the to "**end**"

***e.g : 1-2-3-4-5-6-7-8-9-10-11-12-end***

And thanks to all of you guys.

Comment: In the loop check if you are equal to the max number and if so return end.

Comment: @TobyAllen but how can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with:


`">" . ($p == count($pages) ? "end" : $p) . "</option>"`


instead of


`">" . $p . "</option>"`


For optimization reasons you might want to buffer `count($pages)` into a variable before the `for`.

Comment: I'll try this and I'll see